# finding an string expression in an sentence

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have like a three word expression: "Shut The Door" and I want to find it in a sentence. Since They are kind of seperated by space what would be the best solution for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the string:

```
string sample = "If you know what's good for you, you'll shut the door!";
```

And you want to find where it is in a sentence, you can use the IndexOf method.

```
int index = sample.IndexOf("shut the door");
// index will be 42
```

A non -1 answer means the string has been located. -1 means it does not exist in the string. Please note that the search string ("shut the door") is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Use build in Regex.Match Method for matching strings.

```
string text = "One car red car blue car";
string pat = @"(\w+)\s+(car)";
// Compile the regular expression.
Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
// Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.
Match m = r.Match(text);
int matchCount = 0;
while (m.Success) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("Match"+ (++matchCount));
   for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) 
   {
      Group g = m.Groups[i];
      Console.WriteLine("Group"+i+"='" + g + "'");
      CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;
      for (int j = 0; j < cc.Count; j++) 
      {
         Capture c = cc[j];
         System.Console.WriteLine("Capture"+j+"='" + c + "', Position="+c.Index);
      }
   }
   m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match(v=vs.71).aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308252

Comment: Regex has a lot of overhead, which I'm not sure is needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string1.indexOf(string2) >= 0)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are nothing special, they are just characters, so you can find a string like this like yuo would find any other string in your sentence, for example using "indexOf" if you need the position, or just "Contains" if you need to know if it exists or not.

E.g.

```
    string sentence = "foo bar baz";
    string phrase = "bar baz";

    Console.WriteLine(sentence.Contains(phrase)); // True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some C# code to find a substrings using a start string and end string point but you can use as a base and modify (i.e. remove need for end string) to just find your string...
2 versions, one to just find the first instance of a substring, other returns a dictionary of all starting positions of the substring and the actual string.

```
    public Dictionary<int, string> GetSubstringDic(string start, string end, string source, bool includeStartEnd, bool caseInsensitive)
{
    int startIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;
    int length = -1;
    int sourceLength = source.Length;
    Dictionary<int, string> result = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    try
    {
        //if just want to find string, case insensitive
        if (caseInsensitive)
        {
            source = source.ToLower();
            start = start.ToLower();
            end = end.ToLower();
        }

        //does start string exist
        startIndex = source.IndexOf(start);
        if (startIndex != -1)
        {
            //start to check for each instance of matches for the length of the source string
            while (startIndex < sourceLength && startIndex > -1)
            {
                //does end string exist?
                endIndex = source.IndexOf(end, startIndex + 1);
                if (endIndex != -1)
                {
                    //if we want to get length of string including the start and end strings
                    if (includeStartEnd)
                    {
                        //make sure to include the end string
                        length = (endIndex + end.Length) - startIndex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //change start index to not include the start string
                        startIndex = startIndex + start.Length;
                        length = endIndex - startIndex;
                    }
                    //add to dictionary
                    result.Add(startIndex, source.Substring(startIndex, length));
                    //move start position up
                    startIndex = source.IndexOf(start, endIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    //no end so break out of while;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Notify of Error
         result = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        StringBuilder g_Error = new StringBuilder();
        g_Error.AppendLine("GetSubstringDic: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        g_Error.AppendLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}

public string GetSubstring(string start, string end, string source, bool includeStartEnd, bool caseInsensitive)
{
    int startIndex = -1;
    int endIndex = -1;
    int length = -1;
    int sourceLength = source.Length;
    string result = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        if (caseInsensitive)
        {
            source = source.ToLower();
            start = start.ToLower();
            end = end.ToLower();
        }

        startIndex = source.IndexOf(start);
        if (startIndex != -1)
        {
            endIndex = source.IndexOf(end, startIndex + 1);
            if (endIndex != -1)
            {
                if (includeStartEnd)
                {
                    length = (endIndex + end.Length) - startIndex;
                }
                else
                {
                    startIndex = startIndex + start.Length;
                    length = endIndex - startIndex;
                }
                result = source.Substring(startIndex, length);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Notify of Error
        result = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder g_Error = new StringBuilder();
        g_Error.AppendLine("GetSubstring: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        g_Error.AppendLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure the check ignores the case of both phrases.

```
string theSentence = "I really want you to shut the door.";
string thePhrase = "Shut The Door";

bool phraseIsPresent = theSentence.ToUpper().Contains(thePhrase.ToUpper());
int phraseStartsAt = theSentence.IndexOf(
    thePhrase, 
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine("Is the phrase present? " + phraseIsPresent);
Console.WriteLine("The phrase starts at character: " + phraseStartsAt);
```

This outputs:

```
Is the phrase present? True
The phrase starts at character: 21
```